# Variable in Thermodynamics

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics

While studying Physical Chemistry, I came up with this question.
As I derive equation C_p-C_v, I found the equation (dQ/dT)p = T(dS/dT)p (d-> round)

As I know, dQ=TdS so dQ/dT=(Tds/dT). and I'm still curious that why (Tds/dT)= dS+T(dS/dT).
Can we consider T as a constant value although the differentiating variable is T?

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to ChemSE! Please find guidance for MathJaX / $\LaTeX$ as follows and reformat your post - [Basics](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/notation) // [MathJaX and mhchem formatting for equations and chemical formulae](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/faq-how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-on-chemistry-stack-exchange) // [Guidelines on which should be upright / italics](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/443/which-symbols-are-written-in-roman-upright-font-and-which-are-italicized)

Comment: Also you can refer [How to use MathJaX](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).